# How do I read in inputs into an array in c++?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
Using namespace std;
int main() {
    int i;
    char array[5];
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cin >> array[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i; < 5; i++) {
        cout << array[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my code. I face some compilation errors. Please advise.

Comment: What errors, exactly ? Why not copy and paste them into your question ?

Comment: I face some comprehension errors with your question. Please advise.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i; < 5; i++)`, really? Eyes open, friend. Please try to debug your code for a little longer than a few minutes before posting it on the internet!

Comment: cannot convert '__complex__ int' to 'int' in assignment
HelloWorld.cpp:16:14: error: expected primary-expression before '<' token this my error encoutered

Comment: what errors do you get/?

Comment: no more errors thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Using namespace std;
 //^^typo?: results in syntax error. no keyword `Using` in C++
```

should be:

```
using namespace std;
```

BTW: you should not prefer to put `using namespace std` at beginning of header or source files, instead, try to use:
    `std::cout` and `std::endl`.

Comment: Typoes are by definition "too localised" :|